# Lambda Calculus, defining the AND boolean operator.

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am learning lambda calculus and I was given the following assignment:

Working with these definitions of TRUE and FALSE:

> λx y . x ≡ T
>
> λx y . y ≡ F

I am asked to form the AND operator, that even though functions similarly, is not equivalent to the following definition of it:

> ∧ ≡ λx y .x y F

But everywhere I've checked this seems to be the only way to go at it. Can anyone provide any guidance as to how I should start thinking about it?

Comment: What does"equivalent" mean here exactly?   The first thing I'd want to look at would be, how similar my solution be and still be considered"inequivalent"?

Comment: Not syntactically the same I suppose.

Comment: In that case, my hint is: the AND operation is commutative.

Comment: Does this mean that:  ∧ ≡ λx y .y x F would be a sufficient solution? Looking at it it seems too simple to be right. Weird.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans) Wikipedia article contains alternative encoding.

Comment: I don't know if $ λx y .y x F$ would be a sufficient solution, because it turns on the meaning of “inequivalent”.  If it means “not syntactically the same”, as you suggested, then it's fine.  Other things you could consider are: $\eta$-expansion of the formula you have; or rewriting $x\land y$ as $\text{if } x \text{ then } x \text{ else } y$.

Comment: I meant "if y then x else y".

Comment: I just learned what exactly they meant with "inequivalent". It basically means, that if we were to plug in each function something other than boolean values, they would have different outcomes.